# Rails - Puma - Nginx : Can't verify CSRF token authenticity the HTTP or HTTPS enabled on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I have an issue about Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

I use versions:

- Ruby 2.4.1
- Rails 5.1.1
- Devise 4.3.0
- Nginx and Puma 3.9.1

My /views/layout/application.html.erb

...
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
...

Here is the nginx.conf file:

```
upstream puma-enziin {
  server unix:///home/kevin/websites/enziin/shared/tmp/sockets/enziin-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name enziin.com;

  root /home/kevin/websites/enziin/current/public;

  access_log /home/kevin/websites/enziin/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/kevin/websites/enziin/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    # Some browsers still send conditional GET requests if there's a
    # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
    # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma-enziin;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

After restart Puma and Nginx, login page :

Started POST "/login" for 125.234.98.102 at 2017-06-22 09:58:24 +0000
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SEFj/KRPxWJF5x/TE0IR6LlvBr4701BzQc4EfWFlJYvyWkIMo9TZut3mUMRxxLtozi9TsfmBuaUUlFN5dzR2NQ==", "user"=>{"email"=>"oceandemy@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "otp_code_token"=>"", "remember_me"=>"0"}}

Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.

Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken 
(ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):

Thanks for any idea.